# Can personal profiles be removed on work devices?

Tags: profiles, restricted-profiles

We're looking at rolling out 100+ android devices and would like to lock them down to managed profiles. This is mainly to prevent excessive data usage (youtube and the like) - Android for work allows us to whitelist apps, set policy etc; but this is in addition to the standard user account.

This is cost sensitive, so is there a solution out there that will allow us to lock the phone down to only the managed work profile so that additional applications cannot be installed?

Comment: Why dont you use Device Owner ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use apps like [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en) and lock the Play store: this way, without a password set by you the user shouldn't be able to install anything. I don't know if there are better solutions, maybe already implemented in android for work; and I don't know, more important, if this has any drawback on app updates. But worth a try, if you have no other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood what you want is a way to manage multiple devices and add restrictions and do other configurations for multiple devices at once.
If so, you can go for a [Enterprise Mobility Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_mobility_management) System. There are opensource EMMs as well which you won't need to pay.